# RESTAssured Multipart content-type

Tags: rest, cucumber, rest-assured, gherkin, cucumber-java

I started using RESTAssured recently and am making a REST call using the RESTAssured library.

I have an attachment in the request which I am attaching using the `"multipart()"` method. For my API I should be passing `"application/x-abc-xyz+xml"` as the Content-Type.

When I tried setting this using `" contentType()"` I get below error, however preceding the content-type with `"multipart/"` will resolve this error but I am not getting the REST response from the server because it expects the content-type without the `"multipart/"` prefix.

I need help in resolving this issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type application/x-hub-multipart+xml is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/". 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.registerRestAssuredEncoders
```

Answer (score 2):

**it may work, you can try this , E.g: Attachment file type as ".png"**

```
Response response = given()
                                   .multiPart(new MultiPartSpecBuilder(resourceFile).fileName(filename)
                                                                                    // controlName is the name of the
                                                                                    // RequestParam associated with the
                                                                                    // MultipartFile[] array
                                                                                    .controlName("file")
                                                                                    .mimeType("image/png")
                                                                                    .build())
                                   .param("documentType", "MyCat")  // You can omit this if U want
                                   .when()
                                   .post("my URI")
                                   .then()
                                   .extract()
                                   .response();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this. You are not passing any content type in your code so it will take "multipart/form-data" as the default content-type. In my case I am trying to pass "application/x-abc-xyz+xml" as the content-type.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the content type like:

```
.header("Content-Type", "multipart/json")
```

Comment: thank you, sir! in my case it was missing header for "multipart/form-data" which my controller accept.

Answer (score 0):

// add attachments example of jira API. Make sure to enable attachement

```
given().log().all().header("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check").filter(session)
    .pathParam("Key", "10004")
    .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
    .multiPart("file",new File("FilePath"))

    .when().post("/rest/api/2/issue/{Key}/attachments").then().log().all()
    .assertThat().statusCode(200);
```