# Java+restassured remove Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary from multipart request

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I'm currently testing a very specific API, that refuses to accept a request which has Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary. I throws a 415 - unsupported media type error. However, when I send the same file and build the same request using postman, it accepts it without issues. Looking at the logs of what is received in the service, the only difference in the two requests is that the restassured one has Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary in the body. Here's how it looks:

[image]

So for the sake of debugging and pinpointing if this is indeed the cause of the request failing, I would like to remove Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary from the body. yet I have no idea how. I tried using the following code, yet the request still arrives with it present. Here is the code I'm using:

```
request = given()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + LoginSteps.accessToken)
            .queryParam("memberId", memberId)
            .multiPart("receipt", new File(receiptFilePath), "image/jpeg")
            .urlEncodingEnabled(false)
            .config(RestAssuredConfig.config()
                    .encoderConfig(EncoderConfig
                            .encoderConfig()
                            .appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)
                            .encodeContentTypeAs("image/jpeg", io.restassured.http.ContentType.ANY)));

request.post(baseUrl + endpoint);
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of Content-Transfer-Encoding from this request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RESTAssured Multipart content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531172/restassured-multipart-content-type)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It deals with the conten-type in the header of the request, and not the Content-Transfer-Encoding in the body which is what is causing my problems

Comment: Postman add an additional header to your request, compare those headers with yours and add missing to your RA code

Comment: any resolution , u found for this?

Comment: Yeah, it just started working one day and I still don't know why